# Saving an ExcelPackage with exclusive lock of excel, giving error after opening excel file - C# - EPPlus

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, epplus

My objective is to write some data into an excel.

Here i am opening a file with file stream by exclusive lock (FileMode.Open, FileShare.Read etc., I need to lock the file to restrict others writing into excel while i am processing.) then writing some content into it and finally close the stream, so that other threads can write into this file. I am using EPPlus(5.7.4) version.

The code i am using here is :

```
public void WriteToExcel()
{
     using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.Read))
     using (var excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(stream))
     {
         DoSomething(excelPackage);
         excelPackage.SaveAs(stream);
         stream.Close();
     }
}

public void DoSomething(ExcelPackage excelPackage)
{
     var cell = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets[0].Cells[2, 3];
     cell.Value = "some value";
}
```

I put a break point in using statement and opened excel in the middle of execution and it showing a message saying like below which is correct.

[image: Image, after locking excel file]

But once i finish with execution when i try to open excel file it showing below error message.

**We found a problem with some content in Sample.xlsx. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can? if you trust the source of this book, Click Yes**

[image: Image, getting error message]

I tried in different ways but none worked for me, as same error message is displaying. Can someone help me resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're reading from and rewriting to the same file stream simultaneously.

You can test this by changing `excelPackage.SaveAs(new FileInfo("Book2.xlsx"));` and create a new file - your file will be created without any issues.

You could open your original document, write the changes to a new file, then delete the original file and rename the new file back to the original name:

```cs
ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;
using (var stream = new FileStream("Book1.xlsx", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.Read))
using (var excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(stream))
{
    DoSomething(excelPackage);
    excelPackage.SaveAs(new FileInfo("Book2.xlsx"));
}

File.Delete("Book1.xlsx");
File.Move("Book2.xlsx", "Book1.xlsx");
```

The caveat with this is that if you have multiple things trying to access that file, then they might throw `FileNotFound` exceptions if they happen to try to open `Book1.xlsx` after it's delete and before `Book2.xlsx` is renamed.

That said, if you're dealing with that level of parallelism then you shouldn't be using a Excel file.

Side note: You don't need `stream.Close();` as the `using` block automatically closes the stream.

Comment: Your answer was downvoted because it doesn't answer anything. It also doesn't do what OP needs, which is to keep the file locked whilst it's being written. `FileInfo` doesn't do that.

Answer (score -1):

Below code useful to me, you can refer it.

```
 public void WriteToExcel()
 {
     string path = @"C:\Use**op\aa.xlsx";
     FileInfo file = new FileInfo(path);
     ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;
     using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(file))
     {
         DoSomething(package);
     }
 }

 public void DoSomething(ExcelPackage package)
 {
     ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[0];
     worksheet.Cells[2,4].Value = "some value";
     package.Save();
 }
```

[image]